# Task Scheduler shortcut not working

Tags: shortcuts, uac

I'm trying to launch a shortcut from this guide: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/stop-annoying-uac-prompts-how-to-create-a-user-account-control-whitelist-windows/

But the shortcut refuse to launch the task. I ran the task to make sure it is working and it is.
My shortcut looks like this:

C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /RUN /TN “\Allow\Launcher"

When I double click on the shortcut, nothing happens... kind of pulling my hair since I have been playing around with this for an hour, deleting, recreating, trying different combinations of the shortcut, etc.

Comment: It you watch the Task Manager, does schtasks run at all?  If you manually run the above line from a command prompt, does it return an results/errors?  How about if you just manually run the task from the GUI?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Good idea on running from the command prompt. I does give me an error message: "ERROR: The system cannot find the path specified." Which I don't understand since that's my folder name and I copy and pasted the task name too.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't add slash before folder name, in your case:

   `C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /RUN /TN "Allow\Launcher"`
2. Open 'Settings' tab of task properties, make sure the "**Allow task to be run on demand**" option is checked.

[image]